# Dependencies flags "module could not be found on disk" even though the DLL is there

Tags: windows, dll, dependencies, dependency-walker

I've been using [Dependency Walker](https://www.dependencywalker.com/)'s successor, [Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies), to troubleshoot some errors with a legacy application I'm working on.  I've noticed that Dependencies flagged a DLL as missing (let's call it Foo.dll), but even after I manually copied it to the working tree and refreshed the app I still got the dependency flagged with following error message:

```
Foo.dll module could not be found on disk
```

Does anyone have any insight on what would lead Dependencies to flag a DLL that exists in the current path as "module could not be found on disk" ?